# PS - MS Teams locate Private Channels URL (from specific sites or members)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I am stuck in the following script.  The script below works fine to locate the user's team's group, email, and URL.  We have recently discovered that some MS Teams contain MS Team Private Channels.  We would also like to know if any of those teams (ms teams users are members of) have private channels, and download the name of the channel and the URL.

The following site shows how to find those private channels' URLs from the whole company.
https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/report-private-teams-excel/README.html?tabs=pnpps

But I only need the private channel URL from specific sites.

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

$CustodianTeams = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the user ID and @domain. i.e, UserID@Microsoft.com"
$Custodianteams = $CustodianTeams -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',' '

$TeamIDs = Get-Team -User $CustodianTeams 
   foreach ($TeamID in $TeamIDs) {
      Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity $TeamID.GroupID | select DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress, SharePointSiteUrl | Export-Csv .\$CustodianTeams.csv -Append
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of specific sites?

Comment: Hi,  the script I have collects the DisplayName, Primary SMTPAddress, and SharePointSite of a specific user.  From those sites, I want to know which ones have private channels.  Thank you

Comment: We are checking this internally. We will update you soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please refer below steps:

First install and connect:

Install-Module PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 2.2.4.1
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -RequiredVersion 3.0.0
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

Then:
1. Copy the ps1 file to your downloads folder
2. cd C:\Users\username\Downloads
3. .\TeamsChannelMemberReport.ps1

Choose option 2 to export all and it will export to downloads.

Save this as TeamsChannelMemberReport.ps1:

<#
.Requires -version 2 - Connect-MicrosoftTeams and then Run the script in Powershell

.SYNOPSIS
.\TeamsChannelMemberReport.ps1 - It Can Display all the Teams and its Channels and its members on a List
Or It can Export to a CSV file
With Export of Specific teams
Example 1
PS C:\Scripts> .\TeamsChannelMemberReportv1.0.ps1
Teams Channel Member Report
----------------------------
1.Display in Microsoft Teams Shell
2.Export to CSV File
3.Display Specific Microsoft Team in Shell
4.Export Specific Microsoft Team to CSV File
Choose The Task: 1
User SMTP Address Role Channel DisplayName Team DisplayName
----------------- ---- ------------------- ----------------
Email address removed Owner General Teams_Azure365pro
Email address removed Member General Teams_Azure365pro
Email address removed Member General Teams_Azure365pro
Email address removed Owner General Teams_Azure365pro
Email address removed Member General Teams_Azure365pro
Email address removed Member General Teams_Azure365pro
Email address removed Owner General InformationTec...
Email address removed Member General InformationTec...
Email address removed Owner ServiceDesk Team InformationTec...
Email address removed Owner Infrastructure Team InformationTec...
Example 2
PS C:\Scripts> .\TeamsChannelMemberReportv1.0.ps1
Teams Channel Member Report
----------------------------
1.Display in Microsoft Teams Shell
2.Export to CSV File
3.Display Specific Microsoft Team in Shell
4.Export Specific Microsoft Team to CSV File
Choose The Task: 2
Enter the Path of CSV file (Eg. C:\Teams.csv): c:\teams.csv

#>

Write-host "
Teams Channel Member Report
----------------------------
1.Display in Microsoft Teams Shell
2.Export to CSV File
3.Display Specific Microsoft Team in Shell
4.Export Specific Microsoft Team to CSV File"-ForeGround "Cyan"

#----------------
# Script
#----------------

Write-Host " "

$number = Read-Host "Choose The Task"
$output = @()
switch ($number)
{

1 {
$i = 0
$AllTeams = Get-Team
Foreach ($Team in $AllTeams)
{
$AllChannels = Get-TeamChannel -GroupID $Team.GroupID
Foreach ($Channel in $AllChannels)
{
$AllMembers = Get-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $Team.GroupID -DisplayName $channel.DisplayName
Foreach ($member in $AllMembers)
{
$userObj = New-Object PSObject
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "User SMTP Address" -Value $member.User
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Role" -Value $member.role
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Channel DisplayName" -Value $Channel.DisplayName
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team DisplayName" -Value $Team.DisplayName

$output += $UserObj

}
}
# update counters and write progress
$i++
Write-Progress -activity "Scanning Teams . . .Channels . . . Members" -status "Scanned: $i of $($AllTeams.Count)" -percentComplete (($i / $AllTeams.Count) * 100)
Write-Output $Output
}
;Break}

2 {
$i = 0
$CSVfile = Read-Host "Enter the Path of CSV file (Eg. C:\Teams.csv)"
$AllTeams = Get-Team
Foreach ($Team in $AllTeams)
{
$AllChannels = Get-TeamChannel -GroupID $Team.GroupID
Foreach ($Channel in $AllChannels)
{
$AllMembers = Get-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $Team.GroupID -DisplayName $channel.DisplayName
Foreach ($member in $AllMembers)
{
$userObj = New-Object PSObject
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $member.Name
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "UserId" -Value $member.UserId
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "User SMTP Address" -Value $member.User
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Role" -Value $member.role
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Channel DisplayName" -Value $Channel.DisplayName
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Channel Description" -Value $Channel.Description
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Channel MembershipType" -Value $Channel.MembershipType
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team GroupID" -Value $Team.GroupId
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team DisplayName" -Value $Team.DisplayName
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team Description" -Value $Team.Description
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team Visibility" -Value $Team.Visibility
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team MailNickName" -Value $Team.MailNickName
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team Classification" -Value $Team.Classification
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team Archived" -Value $Team.Archived
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowGiphy" -Value $Team.AllowGiphy
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team GiphyContentRating" -Value $Team.GiphyContentRating
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowStickersAndMemes" -Value $Team.AllowStickersAndMemes
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowGuestCreateUpdateChannels" -Value $Team.AllowGuestCreateUpdateChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowGuestDeleteChannels" -Value $Team.AllowGuestDeleteChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowCreateUpdateChannels" -Value $Team.AllowCreateUpdateChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowCreatePrivateChannels" -Value $Team.AllowCreatePrivateChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowDeleteChannels" -Value $Team.AllowDeleteChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowAddRemoveApps" -Value $Team.AllowAddRemoveApps
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowCreateUpdateRemoveTabs" -Value $Team.AllowCreateUpdateRemoveTabs
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowCreateUpdateRemoveConnectors" -Value $Team.AllowCreateUpdateRemoveConnectors
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowUserEditMessages" -Value $Team.AllowUserEditMessages
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowUserDeleteMessages " -Value $Team.AllowUserDeleteMessages
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowOwnerDeleteMessages" -Value $Team.AllowOwnerDeleteMessages
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowTeamMentions" -Value $Team.AllowTeamMentions
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowChannelMentions" -Value $Team.AllowChannelMentions
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team ShowInTeamsSearchAndSuggestions" -Value $Team.ShowInTeamsSearchAndSuggestions

$output += $UserObj

}
}
# update counters and write progress
$i++
Write-Progress -activity "Scanning Teams . . .Channels . . . Members" -status "Scanned: $i of $($AllTeams.Count)" -percentComplete (($i / $AllTeams.Count) * 100)
$output | Export-csv -Path $CSVfile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

}
;Break}

3 {
$i = 0
$Teamname = Read-Host "Enter the Team Display name or Range (Eg. Teamname , Team*,*Team)"
$AllTeams = Get-Team | Where-object {$_.DisplayName -like $Teamname}
Foreach ($Team in $AllTeams)
{
$AllChannels = Get-TeamChannel -GroupID $Team.GroupID
Foreach ($Channel in $AllChannels)
{
$AllMembers = Get-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $Team.GroupID -DisplayName $channel.DisplayName
Foreach ($member in $AllMembers)
{
$userObj = New-Object PSObject
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "User SMTP Address" -Value $member.User
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Role" -Value $member.role
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Channel DisplayName" -Value $Channel.DisplayName
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team DisplayName" -Value $Team.DisplayName

$output += $UserObj

}
}
# update counters and write progress
$i++
Write-Progress -activity "Scanning Teams . . .Channels . . . Members" -status "Scanned: $i of $($AllTeams.Count)" -percentComplete (($i / $AllTeams.Count) * 100)
Write-Output $Output
}
;Break}

4 {
$i = 0
$CSVfile = Read-Host "Enter the Path of CSV file (Eg. C:\Teams.csv)"
$Teamname = Read-Host "Enter the Team Display name or Range (Eg. Teamname , Team*,*Team)"
$AllTeams = Get-Team | Where-object {$_.DisplayName -like $Teamname}
Foreach ($Team in $AllTeams)
{
$AllChannels = Get-TeamChannel -GroupID $Team.GroupID
Foreach ($Channel in $AllChannels)
{
$AllMembers = Get-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $Team.GroupID -DisplayName $channel.DisplayName
Foreach ($member in $AllMembers)
{
$userObj = New-Object PSObject
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $member.Name
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "UserId" -Value $member.UserId
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "User SMTP Address" -Value $member.User
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Role" -Value $member.role
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Channel DisplayName" -Value $Channel.DisplayName
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Channel Description" -Value $Channel.Description
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Channel MembershipType" -Value $Channel.MembershipType
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team GroupID" -Value $Team.GroupId
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team DisplayName" -Value $Team.DisplayName
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team Description" -Value $Team.Description
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team Visibility" -Value $Team.Visibility
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team MailNickName" -Value $Team.MailNickName
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team Classification" -Value $Team.Classification
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team Archived" -Value $Team.Archived
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowGiphy" -Value $Team.AllowGiphy
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team GiphyContentRating" -Value $Team.GiphyContentRating
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowStickersAndMemes" -Value $Team.AllowStickersAndMemes
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowGuestCreateUpdateChannels" -Value $Team.AllowGuestCreateUpdateChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowGuestDeleteChannels" -Value $Team.AllowGuestDeleteChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowCreateUpdateChannels" -Value $Team.AllowCreateUpdateChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowCreatePrivateChannels" -Value $Team.AllowCreatePrivateChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowDeleteChannels" -Value $Team.AllowDeleteChannels
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowAddRemoveApps" -Value $Team.AllowAddRemoveApps
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowCreateUpdateRemoveTabs" -Value $Team.AllowCreateUpdateRemoveTabs
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowCreateUpdateRemoveConnectors" -Value $Team.AllowCreateUpdateRemoveConnectors
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowUserEditMessages" -Value $Team.AllowUserEditMessages
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowUserDeleteMessages " -Value $Team.AllowUserDeleteMessages
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowOwnerDeleteMessages" -Value $Team.AllowOwnerDeleteMessages
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowTeamMentions" -Value $Team.AllowTeamMentions
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team AllowChannelMentions" -Value $Team.AllowChannelMentions
$userObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Team ShowInTeamsSearchAndSuggestions" -Value $Team.ShowInTeamsSearchAndSuggestions

$output += $UserObj

}
}
# update counters and write progress
$i++
Write-Progress -activity "Scanning Teams . . .Channels . . . Members" -status "Scanned: $i of $($AllTeams.Count)" -percentComplete (($i / $AllTeams.Count) * 100)
$output | Export-csv -Path $CSVfile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

};
Break
}

Default {Write-Host "No matches found, Enter Options 1 or 2" -ForeGround "red"}

}
```